# Localhost to Staging to Development Dynamic WP-CONFIG

Tags: database, wp-config, customization, staging

I am trying to setup 3 environments: Localhost, Staging and Development.
The issue is that each environment has its own db.

We want to have ONE config file which will dynamically change the Db connection.

Example:

`Dev Db = define('DB_NAME', 'dev.domainname.com');
Staging Db = define('DB_NAME', 'staging.domainname.com');
Production Db = define('DB_NAME', 'domainname.com');`

**In the WP-CONFIG, I was going to add the following function to do the conditional as:**

```
function SetEnvironment()
{
        $envname = '';

        if ( stristr( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], "localhost" ) ) {     $envname = 'dev.'    }

        if ( stristr( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], "staging" ) ) {    $envname = 'staging.'    }

        return $envname;
}
```

**In the WP-CONFIG set:**

```
    /** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', SetEnvironment() + 'domainname.com');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'someusernamehere');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'somepasswordhere');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', SetEnvironment() + 'domainname.com');
```

Is there a better way of doing a dynamic settings in WP-CONFIG?

Comment: There is a great post on the subject https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/wordpress-local-dev-tips/

Comment: You may be interested in [bedrock](https://roots.io/bedrock/docs/configuration-files/) - it's a fairly major overhaul of the typical wordpress file structure, but it does have some nice features including environment-aware configs built-in.